# How can I get media query to resize div based on the width of the screen?

Tags: html, css, styling

I am working on a search engine for my website where results are displayed within a div along the middle of the page. Since I would like the search engine portion to be useable on mobile as well, I decided to use a media query to change the width of the div that search results are contained in to be 100% when the width of the screen is less than or equal to 500px, using the following media style rules:

```
#result_box {
    width: 60vmin;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color:red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #result_box {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

With the following chunk of html:

```
 <body>
        <?php $var_value = $_SESSION['query_literal']; ?>
       
        <div class="result_entry">
            
            <hr id="seperator">

            <div id="result_box">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

However, the width of my 'result_box' is still 60vmin when I test on a mobile device. Does anyone have any idea how I can change this?

Comment: Are you sure the parent element `result_entry` has full screen width?

Comment: what resolution the mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you didn't set the viewport meta correctly in header or forgot at all about it.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

With this the the browser knows how to control the page dimensions and scaling.
Basically without it your website won't work responsivly.

**width=device-width** means you set to the width of the page to follow the screen-width of your device

**initial-scale=1.0** sets the zoom level to 1 when the page is loaded